# Implicit conversion error in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of all ID's.

//Code

```
List<IAddress> AllIDs = new List<IAddress>();
AllIDs= AllIDs.Where(s => s.AddressId.Length >= s.AddressId.IndexOf("_"))
              .Select(s => s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")))
              .ToList();
```

I am using the above LINQ query but getting compilation error:

//Error

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List
>   to System.Collections.Generic.List

I want to to substring operation on a member field `AddressId` based on a character "_".

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're trying to assign a `List<string>` to `List<IAddress>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find the addresses you want with the where but then you select some strings from the id.

```
s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")) is string
```

ie 
`Select(s => s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_"))).ToList()`; returns a list of substrings

Just remove it and use

```
AllIDs= AllIDs.Where(s => s.AddressId.Length >= s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")).ToList()
```

as

```
Where(s => s.AddressId.Length >= s.AddressId.IndexOf("_"))
```

filters the list of AllIDs but keeps them as `IAddress`s

if you rewrite is like this you should be able to see what the problem is

you said

```
var items  = from addr in AllIds 
             where addr.AddressId.Length >= addr.AddressId.IndexOf("_") // filter applied
             select addr.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")); // select a string from the address

AllIDs = items.ToList(); // hence the error List<string> can't be assigned to List<IAddress>
```

but you wanted

```
var items  = from addr in AllIds 
             where addr.AddressId.Length >= addr.AddressId.IndexOf("_") // filter applied
             select addr;                        // select the address

AllIDs = items.ToList(); // items contains IAddress's so this returns a List<IAddress>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update `AddressId` with a Linq query, you can do it this way:

```
AllIDs.Where(s => s.AddressId.Length >= s.AddressId.IndexOf("_"))
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(s => s.AddressId = s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")));
```

Note that [.ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bwabdf9z.aspx) is not a Linq extension, but a method of the class List< T >.

Since IndexOf could be time consuming, think about caching the value:

```
AllIDs.Select(s => new { Address = s, IndexOf_ = s.AddressId.IndexOf("_") })
      .Where(s => s.Address.AddressId.Length >= s.IndexOf_ )
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(s => s.Address.AddressId = s.Address.AddressId.Substring(s.IndexOf_ ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select operation `.Select(s => s.AddressId.Substring(s.AddressId.IndexOf("_")))` does not modify your objects, it projects each object to a substring. Thus `.ToList()` returns a `List<string>`.